# Can I portably define a variable based on a function argument?

Tags: shell, sh

I'd like to define a function `defvar` which defines a variable, e.g.

```
defvar FOO BAR  ## equivalent to FOO=BAR
```

However, the naive way of defining such a function does not work (presumedly because the shell ends up executing the whole string as a single command?)

```
defvar () { $1=$2; } ## no dice
```

One way around this is to explicitly perform the assignment as part of an `export` call, e.g.

```
defvar () { export $1=$2; } ## works, but not portable to some older shells
```

which works in my local `bash` shell, but it sounds like this may [not be portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193095/where-is-export-var-value-not-available), and may not work on some older shells.

Is there a portable mechanism for accomplishing this?

Comment: That *is* portable, in the useful sense of the word.

Comment: I don't think that will work in the original Bourne shell, but hopefully you can draw the line at POSIX(+) compatibility. Hm.. not sure about `ash` or `dash`... anyone? Good luck.

Comment: An issue with using export is not that much the lack of portability, but the fact it does more than assigning a shell variable, i.e. what defvar is attempting to do. In addition, it also tags it as an environment variable, i.e. it exports the variable.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using [`eval`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#eval):

```
defvar () {
    eval "$1='$2'"
}
```

We construct a statement to evaluate using the function arguments, e.g. `"$1='$2'"`, and then evaluate the constructed string (thereby performing the assignment).

Since [`eval`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#eval) is defined by the POSIX standard, it's about as portable as it gets. It seems to even work on the [heirloom bourne shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html), so I imagine this will work on even the older shells out there.

That said, using `eval` is kind of icky, since someone could write something like:

```
defvar FOO "'; echo Ouch; '"
```

That is, it's easy to use that to execute arbitrary code, so either this should only be run with trusted inputs, or sanitized / validated input.